# $.getJSON does not retrieve up-to-date information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a MySQL database set up. I have a PHP file that connects to the database and creates an array out of the database's information. It then echoes that array encoded as JSON. I have an HTML file with JavaScript to retrieve this JSON and log it on the console.

**The issue:** When I run the HTML file after updating the table, it won't show the new information. I have to manually run the PHP file that creates the JSON before running the HTML file for the console to show me the updated information. *How do I get the HTML file to always retrieve the most up-to-date information from my database without running the PHP script manually?*

Here is the PHP file (db.php):

```
<?php

include ("database_connect.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM markers";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$array = array();
$i = 0;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($array);

$conn->close();

?>
```

Here is the HTML file (db.html):

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script>
$.getJSON('db.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: How do you run the HTML file and the PHP file? What does it mean to run a PHP file manually?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have the files in my root directory on my website. I had to open the PHP file before opening the HTML file for the HTML file to log updated database information to the console. Felix's answer solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put JQuery code in the script. You have to embed on `onReady()` call; otherwise, it will execute before HTML is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('db.php', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Also, please remove the silly "disclaimer". Nothing wrong being new to development. As long as you read the [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you should be good. Such "disclaimers" are seen as an excuse to ask sloppy question; and you are actually *less* likely to get an answer!

Comment: This works beautifully, although I'm not sure why it works. I'll look into the documentation for the stuff you added.

Comment: Any `JQuery` documentation explains this in details; for example, this: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Make a refresh button on page and asign click listener to it.

```
$(document).on('click', '#refresh_button', function (){

    $.getJSON('db.php', function(data) {
        RefreshTableFunction(data);
    });

});
```

Now the problem is that you need to refresh the page to get data from server (php file)